# Error 400 when trying to exchange authorization code for access token (spotify API)

Tags: javascript, fetch, spotify

I am creating a personal website that has a section music that I listen to from Spotify, I am using Spotify API to do this. So, I have gotten the authorization code and I need to exchange that for an access token, but it's giving me error 400.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get("code");

if (!code) {
    redirectToAuthCodeFlow(client_id);
} else {
    getAccessToken(client_id,code);
  
}

function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(client_id) {        

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", client_id);
    params.append("response_type", "code");
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://127.0.0.1:5500/position.html");
    params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
    document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
}

async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {        

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", client_id);
    params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.append("code", code);
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://127.0.0.1:5500/position.html"); 
    //
    const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: params
    });

    
}
```

I tried using different authorizations but its not working.

Comment: You try to redirect to your localhost IP (127.0.0.1). That won't work. You need your publicly accessible IP.

Comment: @Geshode no, the redirect_uri is where the user will get redirected to _in their own browser_, after granting access in the OAuth providers login screen. So using a local address during development, usually works perfectly fine. (Unless the auth provider would specifically disallow entering such local addresses in the relevant app setting fields, but that is usually not the case.)

Comment: _"but it's giving me error 400"_ - go check what the response body contains, usually you find a human-readable error message in there.

Comment: @CBroe Didn't know that. Thanks for teaching me that. Learning something new every day.